# Using Java/Kotlin inheritance for similar contracts/states/flows

Tags: kotlin, multiple-inheritance, corda

Having done a lot of reading on Corda, its now time to dive in and get my feet wet. My use case has four contracts that have similar functionality and some common data fields, but which also have some of their own flows and validation. They share some validation.

If this was a pure Java app I would be diving straight in with inheritance for the four instantiated classes, based on one common abstract class.

Does the same principal apply with Corda? Or would I be better getting the simplest one working first and then cloning the code and amending it? This seems like a horrible idea that harks back to those bad old days of procedural code. But how will Corda cope with inheritance and overridden validation rules?

Comment: What is the problem with inheritance, at the end its Java code in the cordapp as well. Can you explain with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have too many issues as long as you implement the correct interfaces on the normal corda Contract class.

If you want to create a generic contract "sub-interface" you totally can as long as you support and implement the correct contract methods.

It might look something like this.

```
// Filename: Sports.java
public interface Sports {
   public void setHomeTeam(String name);
   public void setVisitingTeam(String name);
}

// Filename: Football.java
public interface Football extends Sports {
   public void homeTeamScored(int points);
   public void visitingTeamScored(int points);
   public void endOfQuarter(int quarter);
}

// Filename: Hockey.java
public interface Hockey extends Sports {
   public void homeGoalScored();
   public void visitingGoalScored();
   public void endOfPeriod(int period);
   public void overtimePeriod(int ot);
}
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm#:~:text=Extending%20Interfaces,methods%20of%20the%20parent%20interface.